# Anonymise GCP Cloud SQL export for local dev

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, export, cloud

We have routine daily backups of our Cloud SQL (PostGres) instance to a GCS Bucket. I'm looking for ideas and the best route we could take to achieve the following:

- Anonymise sensitive data from the .SQL file after the backup completes - this could be another routine automated job which triggers after the export
- Compress to a .tar.gz (or other format) to make it downloadable in a faster time
- The devs will then download, unzip and run in their local postgres SQL docker container for local dev environments

I've been researching to see if there's a GCP built in service to do this but can't find anything. I would like to use GCP cloud services as much as possible rather than having to script and run this on compute instances etc.

My current thoughts would be to somehow do this using:

- Cloud Functions using Python to do the anonymisation (if thats even possible)
- Cloud scheduler to set a cron job to do this regularly

I'm just not sure of the details and if there's actually anything easier out there.

Comment: Do you know the type of anonymization that you want to achieve? Redac? Pseudomization? Replace? And how many table do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting info about DLP @Iñigo, that will definitely come in handy.

I have also found we use this tool anyway which I wasn't aware of until yesterday!

https://gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer

It works very well and already comes as a docker image.

Comment: Cloud SQL currently does not support that extension: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions

The pg_dump_anon, which comes with that package, also requires the extension to be enabled in the database to get the dump from (cloud sql). So, can't use it either.

Which is a shame. I hope google will add that extension to its cloud sql soon. Or something better. Azure (SQL-Server) db already has similar feature.

Answer (score 2):

### Technical feasibility

There is a Google Cloud [Data Loss Prevention API](https://cloud.google.com/dlp) that you might use to anonymize (mask) data.

Since you're reading data from a Cloud SQL database you might find useful the DLP Proxy for Cloud SQL (see [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/using-a-dlp-proxy-to-interact-with-cloud-sql) ).

With this proxy application you could submit a query to the database inside an instance or container, and anonymize it. You can mount a bucket with fuse and dump the result directly there.